# Showing delete link for comments posted by the logged in users only in PHP

Tags: php

I have a page which shows the comments posted by all users. Here I need to show a delete link on the side of the comments posted by that current logged in user and he should be able to delete that comment too (like in Facebook, Orkut or any Blogging site). The sample code which I have tried is:

```
<?php
$user_id = 1;
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("blog", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM replies");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $replies = $row;
  if($replies['poster_id' == $user_id]){
      $delete = '<a href="#">Delete</a>';
  }

  echo $replies['poster_id']?></a>&nbsp;¦&nbsp;<?php echo $replies['reply_text']?>&nbsp;¦&nbsp;  <?php echo $delete?></div>

  <?php echo "<br />";
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Here I have given the user_id which is hardcoded here.
What I got is, delete link is displayed on all comments. I need to display delete link for user_id with "1" only.
Can anyone suggest me to get the solution...Thanks in Advance...

Comment: are you sure that $username is the same as 'poster_id'?  Usually those are made to be two separate things...

Comment: can anyone suggest some solution here..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['reply'],$_GET['where']))
 $result=mysql_query("Delete FROM $replies WHERE entry_id = '$_GET['reply']'");

$username = $session->username;

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $replies WHERE entry_id = '$id' ORDER by reply_id DESC");

while ($i = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$replies = $i;
if ($replies['poster_id'] == $username){
$delete = '<a href="delete?where='.$id.'&reply='.$replies['reply_id'].'">Delete</a>';
}
?>
<div>
<div><a href="profiles/<?php echo $replies['poster_id']?>">
<?php echo     $replies['poster_id']?></a>&nbsp;¦&nbsp;<?php echo     $replies['post_time']?>&nbsp;¦&nbsp;<?php echo $delete?></div>

<div><?php echo $replies['reply_text']?></div>

</div><br/><br/>

<?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of old, and probably already well taken care of, but you forgot a ; after $delete

```
<?php echo $delete?>
```

should be

```
<?php echo $delete; ?>
```